# Jmonkey: Make RigidBodyControl React to Gravity

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I am trying my best to make an object fall, and so far I can't even come close. Here is the code i am trying.

```
    BulletAppState bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();

    cubemesh = new Box(1f,1f,1f);
    Geometry something = new Geometry("cube", cubemesh);
    Material bronze = new Material(assetManager, 
    "Common/MatDefs/Light/Lighting.j3md");
    something.setLocalTranslation(0,1,0);
    bronze.setTexture("DiffuseMap", assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/bronze.jpg"));
    something.setMaterial(bronze);
    rootNode.attachChild(something);

    RigidBodyControl control = new RigidBodyControl(10f);
    Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(0,-9.81f,0);
    something.addControl(control);

    //all the random lines i've tried
    stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
    control.setGravity(direction);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().setGravity(direction);
    rootNode.attachChild(something);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(control);
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are many examples in the jME wiki:
http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_physics
Anyway, did you attach `bulletAppState` to the `AppStateManager`?

Comment: Yes, i added in the line, forgot about it.

Comment: Can you see your object on the screen? Your code does not compile. It also doesn't include all the necessary stuff. Please read http://sscce.org and post a complete example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: done, just use a random jpg. (not in the mood for changing variable names)

Answer (score 2):

The physics in your example do work for me. But using your material, i can't see anything because there's no light.

Try attaching a `Light`:

```java
AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight();
light.setColor(ColorRGBA.White);
rootNode.addLight(light);
```

Trying random lines won't get you very far. I recommend reading the jME wiki so you understand what these lines actually do. Here's a minimalistic example which uses a `Material` that doesn't need light:

```java
public void simpleInitApp() {
    BulletAppState bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
    stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);

    Geometry something = new Geometry("cube", new Box(1,1,1));
    something.setMaterial( new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/ShowNormals.j3md") );
    something.setLocalTranslation(0,2,0);
    something.addControl( new RigidBodyControl(10f) );

    rootNode.attachChild(something);
    bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(something);
}
```

This example displays a colourful falling cube. If this doesn't work for you, there might be something wrong with your jME version or its setup
(I'm using jMonkeyEngine 3.1-alpha1).